# Разбиение элементов массива на отдельные массивы

Tags: javascript

как преобразовать массив элементов в отдельные массивы?
на данный момент массив выглядит следующим образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а должен так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```js
arr1 = [["a"], ["b"], ["c","d"]]
var arr2 = [];
for(var i in arr1){
  let tmp = arr1[i];
  for(var j in tmp){
    arr2.push([tmp[j]])
  }
}
console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`elem.map(e => [e])` — из `["c", "d"]` делает `[["c"], ["d"]]`

Оператор `...` позволяет использовать элементы массива в качестве аргументов функции.

```js
let arr = [
  ["a", "0"],
  ["b"],
  ["c", "d"],
];

for( let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
  if( arr[i].length > 1 ){
    arr.splice( i, 1, ...arr[i].map(e => [e]) );
  }
}

console.log( JSON.stringify( arr ) );
```

Comment: Классно. Я даже + поставил. Что будет если данные немного другие let arr = [
  ["0","a"],
  ["b"],
  ["c", "d"],
];

Comment: @KonstantinEmelyanov упс, перевел на классический цикл, справа налево)

Comment: @KonstantinEmelyanov   подскажите, пожалуйста, как в массив `arr=['a', 'b']` добавить элементы массива `arr2=['1', '2']`,  чтобы на выходе был массив `arr=['a', 'b', '1', '2']`

Comment: @elie_ arr = arr.concat(arr2);